# BottomSheetScrollView doesnot scroll to bottom when gorhom BottomSheet is dragged up slowly

Tags: react-native, scrollview, bottom-sheet, react-native-scrollview

**gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet** BottomSheetScrollView does not scroll to end occasionally. As far as the pattern I observed it does it when you drag it up slowly to the second snapPoint and then to third, then when you scroll it, it doesn't scroll to bottom. But after mount if you drag it quickly, directly to last or third snapPoint it scrolls to bottom just fine.

Tried:

1. A simple BottomSheet with BottomSheetScrollView inside it.
2. With static snapPoints : `const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['60%', '88%', '100%'], []);`
3. Drag the BottomSheet slowly upwards, the BottomSheetScrollView will get stuck at a certain height.

Expected:

BottomSheetScrollView should always scroll to the bottom of the content

Here's the sample code:

```
        <BottomSheet
          ref={bottomSheetRef}
          snapPoints={snapPoints}
          index={0}
          handleComponent={() => null}
          onChange={handleSheetChanges}
          backgroundComponent={props => <BottomSheetBackground {...props} />}
          handleIndicatorStyle={{
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(235, 236, 240, 1)',
          }}>
              <BottomSheetScrollView
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                  style={{ zIndex: 1, flex: 1 }}>
                  <Pressable>
                    {props.children}
                  </Pressable>
              <BottomSheetScrollView>
        </BottomSheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed in version ^4.5.1 after the last update.